# Selenium how to determine if element has child?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, xpath-1.0

I am using Selenium via c#. I use this XPath to get all the children elements

```
element.FindElements(By.XPath("./child::*"));
```

Although if there is no child, it throws an error after a timeout. I am looking for a simple way to determine if it has a child or not to avoid the exception.

Comment: FindElements should never be throwing an exception, though it uses implicit wait if no elements exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your question to get all the *Child Nodes* of a *Parent Node* you can use `FindElements()` method with **following-sibling::*** attribute within *xpath* as follows :

- Sample Code Block :

  ```
  List<IWebElement> textfields = new List<IWebElement>();
  textfields = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//desired_parent_element//following-sibling::*"));
  ```

  **Note** : When `FindElements()` is used inconjunction with *implicitly* or *explicitly* waits, `FindElements()` method will return as soon as there are more than 0 items in the found collection, or will return an empty list if the timeout is reached.
- XPath Details :

  - Description : This *xpath* technique is used to locate the sibling elements of a particular node.
  - Explanation : The *xpath* expression gets the all the sibling elements of the parent element located using **desired_parent_element**.

Answer (score 2):

FindElements returns a list, so you can check the size of the list, if it is zero, it means there are no child elements

Java

```
List<WebElement> childs = rootWebElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//*"));
int numofChildren = childs.size();
```

C#

```
IReadOnlyList<IWebElement> childs = rootWebElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*"));
Int32 numofChildren = childs.Count;
```

Answer (score 1):

**To do in Javascript:**

```
var childElements = await element.findElements(By.xpath('.//*'));
    for (i = 0; i <= childElements.length; i++) {
        var elementId = await childElements[i].getAttribute("id");
        await console.log(elementId);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
bool HasChild(IWebElement element)
{
    //Save implicit timeout to reset it later 
    var temp = driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait;

    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
    bool exists = element.FindElements(By.XPath(".//*")).Count > 0;
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = temp;

    return exists;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is:

```
boolean hasChildren(WebElement node) {
    return node.findElements(By.xpath("./descendant-or-self::*")).size() > 1;
}
```

Comment: Suppose you want to see if there were specific children (or  input or span).  Is there a way you can augment the above (other than node.findElements(By.xpath("input")) which will still take a long time if there is none.